# parallel computing in R stalling with larger computations

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have the following script that bootstraps Cox proportional hazard models. The relevant bit for my question is this:

```
bootest <- unlist(mclapply(1:1000, function(x) bootdif(dt_ukb), mc.cores = 24))
```

I run the script on a server, and it runs in seconds with 24 cores. However, when I increase the number of samples in the dummy dataset from 3,000 to 4,000, the code never finishes, and using htop I can see that it is not using any cores. It just stalls indefinitely, for days even.

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
library(survsim)
library(rms)

# generate dummy dataset ----
tmp_case <- data.frame(eid = seq(1, 1000, by=1),
                       case_control = "case", 
                       incident_CAD_hesin = sample(0:1,1000, replace = TRUE), 
                       follow_up_time_years_inclIncidentCAD = sample(1:10,1000, replace = TRUE))
tmp_control <- data.frame(eid = seq(1, 2000, by=1),
                          case_control = "control", 
                          incident_CAD_hesin = sample(0:1,2000, replace = TRUE), 
                          follow_up_time_years_inclIncidentCAD = sample(1:10,2000, replace = TRUE))


df_ukb <- rbind(tmp_control,tmp_case)

df_ukb <- df_ukb %>%
  mutate(case = ifelse(case_control == "case",1,0))

kable(
  df_ukb %>%
    group_by(case,incident_CAD_hesin) %>% 
    summarise(
      count = n())
)


# survival model ----
df_ukb2 <- df_ukb %>%
  mutate(start =0, 
         stop = follow_up_time_years_inclIncidentCAD, 
         incident_CAD_hesin = as.numeric(incident_CAD_hesin))


myfit <- cph(Surv(start, stop, incident_CAD_hesin) ~
               case,
             data=df_ukb2,
             surv=TRUE,
             x=TRUE,
             y=TRUE)

# Estimate the probability of survival at time, for x=0 and x=1
# define time by half-year, upto 10-year
time <- seq(1, 10,
            length.out=10)

table(df_ukb2$age.bin1)
table(is.na(df_ukb2$age.bin1))


Cnew <- df_ukb2 %>% 
  dplyr::select(incident_CAD_hesin) %>% 
  mutate(case = 0)

Csur <- survest(myfit, 
                newdata = as.data.frame(Cnew),
                times=time)

Cmean <- colMeans(Csur$surv)

Tnew <- df_ukb2 %>% 
  dplyr::select(incident_CAD_hesin) %>% 
  mutate(case = 1)

Tsur <- survest(myfit, 
                newdata = as.data.frame(Tnew),
                times=time)

Tmean <- colMeans(Tsur$surv)

# RD estimate 
RD <- Tmean - Cmean
RD


# Bootstrap confidence intervals ----

dt_ukb <- as.data.table(df_ukb2)

bootdif <- function(dd) {
  time <- seq(1, 10, length.out=10)
  
  db <- dd[, .(eid = sample(eid, replace = TRUE)), keyby = case]
  db <- merge(db[, eid, case], dd, by = c("eid", "case"))
  myfit <- cph(Surv(start, stop, incident_CAD_hesin) ~
                 case,
               data=db,
               surv=TRUE,
               x=TRUE,
               y=TRUE)
  
  Cnew <- db %>% 
    dplyr::select(incident_CAD_hesin) %>% 
    mutate(case = 0)
  
  Csur <- survest(myfit, 
                  newdata = as.data.frame(Cnew),
                  times=time)
  
  Cmean <- colMeans(Csur$surv)
  
  Tnew <- db %>% 
    dplyr::select(incident_CAD_hesin) %>% 
    mutate(case = 1)
  
  Tsur <- survest(myfit, 
                  newdata = as.data.frame(Tnew),
                  times=time)
  
  Tmean <- colMeans(Tsur$surv)
  
  # RD estimate 
  RD <- Tmean - Cmean
  return(RD)
}


bootest <- unlist(mclapply(1:1000, function(x) bootdif(dt_ukb), mc.cores = 24))


bootstrap1 <- bootest[seq(1, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap2 <- bootest[seq(2, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap3 <- bootest[seq(3, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap4 <- bootest[seq(4, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap5 <- bootest[seq(5, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap6 <- bootest[seq(6, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap7 <- bootest[seq(7, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap8 <- bootest[seq(8, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap9 <- bootest[seq(9, length(bootest), 10)]
bootstrap10 <- bootest[seq(10, length(bootest), 10)]

ci1 <- quantile(bootstrap1, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci2 <- quantile(bootstrap2, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci3 <- quantile(bootstrap3, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci4 <- quantile(bootstrap4, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci5 <- quantile(bootstrap5, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci6 <- quantile(bootstrap6, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci7 <- quantile(bootstrap7, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci8 <- quantile(bootstrap8, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci9 <- quantile(bootstrap9, c(0.025, 0.975))
ci10 <- quantile(bootstrap10, c(0.025, 0.975))

ci <- data.frame(
  ci1,ci2,ci3,ci4,ci5,ci6,ci7,ci8,ci9,ci10
)

RD_ci <- rbind(RD,ci)
RD_ci <- t(RD_ci)
RD_ci <- -RD_ci
colnames(RD_ci) <- c("RD","ci.upper","ci.lower")
RD_ci <- as.data.frame(RD_ci)
RD_ci$time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
RD_ci
```

I increase the sample size by modifying tmp_control like this:

```
tmp_control <- data.frame(eid = seq(1, 3000, by=1),
                          case_control = "control", 
                          incident_CAD_hesin = sample(0:1,3000, replace = TRUE), 
                          follow_up_time_years_inclIncidentCAD = sample(1:10,3000, replace = TRUE))
```

But I get the same result (parallel stalls) if I use 2,000 cases and controls, and if I use 100 bootstrap replications instead of 1,000. 4,000 total samples seems to be the breaking point. 3,000 works great and utilizes all specified cores, but 4,000 uses none.

Does this behavior make sense to anyone?

Comment: any chance this is a memory issue?

Comment: I don't think so. I did: 
rlimit_as(5e11)  to increase the memory limit to 500GB, but no change.